# Processing of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
 Latitude   Longitude
-31.563910  147.154312
-33.718234  150.363181
-33.727111  150.371124
```

For further processing, I need to convert it into a format like below:

Sample output:

```
[
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
  {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124}
]
```

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
list1 = []
for index,row in dfLatLong.iterrows():
     list1.append("{lat:" + row['StartLat'] + ", lng:" + row['StartLong'] + "},")
```

Comment: is `df.rename(columns={'Latitude':'lat', 'Longitude':'lng'}).to_json(orient='records')` OK?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get the output in the format specified in Sample output without any quotations.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) with param `orient='records'`:

```
In [40]:
df.to_dict(orient='records')

Out[40]:
[{'Latitude': -31.563909999999996, 'Longitude': 147.154312},
 {'Latitude': -33.718234000000002, 'Longitude': 150.363181},
 {'Latitude': -33.727111000000001, 'Longitude': 150.37112400000001}]
```

You can [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the cols prior to the above to get the names you desire:

```
In [42]:

df.rename(columns={'Latitude':'lat', 'Longitude':'lng'}).to_dict(orient='records')

Out[42]:
[{'lat': -31.563909999999996, 'lng': 147.154312},
 {'lat': -33.718234000000002, 'lng': 150.363181},
 {'lat': -33.727111000000001, 'lng': 150.37112400000001}]
```

**EDIT**

You'll need to walk over the df in order to get the desired output

```
In [59]:
s='['
for i, row in df.iterrows():
   s += '{lat:' + str(row['Latitude']) + ',' + 'lng:' + str(row['Longitude']) + '},' + '\n'
​
s += ']'
s

Out[59]:
'[{lat:-31.56391,lng:147.154312},\n{lat:-33.718234,lng:150.363181},\n{lat:-33.727111,lng:150.371124},\n]'
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to remove the quotations surrounding lat and lng?

Comment: No, they are strings, they won't be valid keys in that case, is there a reason you don't want this?

Comment: Ok, i need to pass this to a javascript function, that function accepts strings without quotations only.

Comment: Please can you update your question with your desired output as this was not clear in your question

Comment: I have added the sample output in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.rename(columns={'Latitude':'lat', 'Longitude':'lng'}).to_json(orient='records').replace('\"', '')
```

Comment: '[{lat:29.708519,lng:-95.61705},{lat:53.5912971,lng:-113.600922},{lat:43.5880966,lng:-79.7750244},{lat:50.28127,lng:-119.256882},{lat:46.173645,lng:-60.24228}]'. Is it possible to remove the quotes in beginning and end?

Comment: I understand this might not be possible as we are using to_json, just wondering whether there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to get list or str on output ?

Comment: I have added my sample output in the question, its a list of strings without any quotes. This is because i have to pass this to a function which accepts input in this format only.